# Access xampp website by using computer name on LAN

Tags: xampp, lan

I have a wordpress site on xampp. On the computer, the website could be access via
    localhost/wordpress

The site could also be reached by the computer name "e7440" by typing the following in the url bar:
    e7440/wordpress

On a network computer, the same path does not work
    e7440/wordpress

Only way I can reach the site is by using the IP address of the computer (i don't like this method). Are there settings I need to set to enable access the site via the computer name?

Comment: Did you try to use the host file?

Comment: using the host file would work but then i would have to edit the host file on every computer on the LAN including mobile devices (which isn't ideal).